# When the Redmine task was created using Java, Server Returned '404 Not found' error occurred

Tags: java, redmine, redmine-api

Software version:redmine 4.2.40  jdk17
Dependencies：

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.taskadapter</groupId>
        <artifactId>redmine-java-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RedmineManager mgr = new RedmineManager("https://localhost/redmine/",
                "c35df9265e9f9929f0648edde4a6ab8547b9f0de");
        try {
            tryGetIssues(mgr);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static void tryGetIssues(RedmineManager mgr) throws Exception {
        Project project = mgr.getProjectByKey("143");
        for (Tracker tk : project.getTrackers()) {
            System.out.println(tk.getId() + "-->" + tk.getName());
        }
        List<Issue> issues = mgr.getIssues("143", null);
 
        for (Issue issue : issues) {
            System.out.println(issue.getId() + issue.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

error occurred：

Exception in thread "main" com.taskadapter.redmineapi.NotFoundException: Server returned '404 not found'. response body:
at com.taskadapter.redmineapi.internal.comm.redmine.RedmineErrorHandler.processContent(RedmineErrorHandler.java:48)
at com.taskadapter.redmineapi.internal.comm.redmine.RedmineErrorHandler.processContent(RedmineErrorHandler.java:22)
at com.taskadapter.redmineapi.internal.comm.ComposingHandler.processContent(ComposingHandler.java:25)
at com.taskadapter.redmineapi.internal.comm.ComposingHandler.processContent(ComposingHandler.java:25)
at com.taskadapter.redmineapi.internal.comm.BaseCommunicator.sendRequest(BaseCommunicator.java:47)
at com.taskadapter.redmineapi.internal.comm.redmine.RedmineAuthenticator.sendRequest(RedmineAuthenticator.java:52)
at com.taskadapter.redmineapi.internal.comm.FmapCommunicator.sendRequest(FmapCommunicator.java:26)
at com.taskadapter.redmineapi.internal.comm.FmapCommunicator.sendRequest(FmapCommunicator.java:26)
at com.taskadapter.redmineapi.internal.comm.BasicSimplifier.sendRequest(BasicSimplifier.java:24)
at com.taskadapter.redmineapi.internal.Transport.send(Transport.java:604)
at com.taskadapter.redmineapi.internal.Transport.getJsonResponseFromGet(Transport.java:511)
at com.taskadapter.redmineapi.internal.Transport.getObjectsListNoPaging(Transport.java:486)
at com.taskadapter.redmineapi.internal.Transport.getObjectsList(Transport.java:458)
at com.taskadapter.redmineapi.IssueManager.getIssues(IssueManager.java:186)
at TaskManager.main(TaskManager.java:27)

It took me a long time to solve the problem; I hope to get your help！

Comment: What happens if you try to open that url in your browser? Is redmine running locally and using the right port?

Comment: I opened that URL and went to RedMine; So far, I haven't found out where the mistake is. But I did it in a different way; Circumvent this error.